# Access Entry from ValueConverter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need access to the entry component that the converter is attached to, so I can change the cursor position with `Entry.CursorPosition`.

I have a BindableObject that is also an IValueConverter, how can I get to the Entry

```
public class MaskConverter : BindableObject, IValueConverter
{

...

}
```

Comment: It's not really easily achievable, but I think you actually want to have a look at the [`Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating) instead. These will help you with extending and retrieving the `Entry` element

Comment: Can you binding your Entry.CursorPosition with a converter and then you can change the cursor position in that converter, something like:   `<Entry CursorPosition="{Binding someValue, Converter={StaticResource convertMethod}, ConverterParameter='' }"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML name the `Entry` and use `x:Reference`:

Converter with `MyEntry` property (`ConvertBack` for `Mode=TwoWay` not shown):

```
public class MyConverter : BindableObject, IValueConverter
{
    public Entry MyEntry { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var entry = MyEntry;
        Debug.WriteLine($"convert:pos:{entry?.CursorPosition}:");
        return (string)value;
    }

    ...
}
```

XAML using `MyEntry` property (`MyText` is a property on the viewmodel, not shown):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" MyEntry="{x:Reference myEntry}" />
  ...
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Entry x:Name="myEntry" Text="{Binding MyText, 
                                       Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
```

Without the `MyEntry` property the named `Entry` might be passed to the converter using `ConverterParameter`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var param = parameter as Entry;
    Debug.WriteLine($"convert:pos:{param?.CursorPosition}:");
    return (string)value;
}
```

XAML when passing the named `Entry` in `ConverterParameter`:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
  ...
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Entry x:Name="myEntry" Text="{Binding MyText, 
                                       Converter={StaticResource myConverter},
                                       ConverterParameter={x:Reference myEntry}}">
```